# Make nav bar scroll when user has zoomed in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I was wondering if there was a way to add a scroll to the nav bar when the user has a zoomed in browser.

Currently, I have my nav bar set to:

```
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
```

Along with a javascript code that makes it stick to the side when the user scrolls on the page.

However, say the user has a browser that is zoomed in 150% or more, half of the nav bar gets cut off and the user is not able to see the other options in the nav bar.  Is there a way to add a scroll when the user has a zoomed in browser?

Here is my code,

HTML:

```
    <header>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="img/logo.png"/>
        </a>
    </div><!-- end logo -->

    <div id="menu_icon"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="about.html" class="selected">About</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="resume.html" class="selected">Resume</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="skills.html" class="selected">Skills</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="gallery.html" class="selected">Map&nbsp;Gallery</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="thesis.html" class="selected">Thesis</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="contact.html" class="selected">Contact</a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav><!--end sidebar-->
                
    <div class="footer clearfix">
        <ul class="social clearfix">
            <li><a href="mailto:md@outlook.com" class="email" target="_blank" data-title="Email"><img src="img/email.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/MD/b6/90b/26b?trk=pub-pbmap" class="linkedin" target="_blank" data-title="LinkedIn"><img src="img/linkedin.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/mD" class="twitter" target="_blank" data-title="Twitter"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MD" class="facebook" target="_blank" data-title="Facebook"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a></li>
        </ul><!-- end social -->
        
        <div class="rights">
            <p>Copyright © MD</p>
        </div><!-- end rights -->
    </div ><!-- end footer -->
</header><!-- end header -->
```

CSS:

```
    /*  Header  */
@media (min-width:1100px) {
    header {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 260px;
        min-height: 100%;
        padding: 0 0 0 50px;
        background: #FFFFFF; 
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 9999;
    }

    header .logo {
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left: -50px;
    }
    
    header nav ul {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 35px;
        margin-left: -15px;
        list-style: none;
    }

    header nav ul li {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    header nav ul li a {
        color: #000000;
        font-family: "raleway-regular", arial;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

    header nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #8AE6B8;
    }
    
    header nav ul li a:active {
        color: #CC99FF;
    }

    .transition {
        width:50%; 
        height: 30px; 
        position: relative; 
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    .transition:hover {
        width:100%; 
        height: 30px;
        position: relative; 
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .sideBar {
        width:75%; 
        height: 100%; 
        position: relative;
        padding:0px;
        margin-left:20%;    
    }

    header .footer {
        margin-top: 30%;
    }
        
    header ul.social {
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);  /* For Webkit browsers */
        filter: gray;  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
        -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;  /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
    }

    header ul.social li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 15px 15px 4px;
    }

    header ul.social li a {
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    header .rights p {
        color: #000000;
        font-family: "raleway-regular", arial;
        font-size: 11px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }

    header .rights a {
        font-family: "raleway-bold", arial;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/n2zb3pnz/

Even on the js fiddle it doesn't show the full nav bar because it is too zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n2zb3pnz/5/

```
header {
  overflow: auto;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so very much, I truly appreciate it!

At first, I tried
    overflw: auto;, however, it did not work.

The 
    bottom:0; did the trick!

Again, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here..

The `<header>` html tag is normally used as a container element for "navigational aids" for some containing element (in your case `<body>`). [From the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header):

> The HTML  Element represents a group of introductory or
>   navigational aids. It may contain some heading elements but also other
>   elements like a logo, wrapped section's header, a search form, and so
>   on.

.. So, it's not semantically incorrect, but think of it's typically usage as being the top portion of a "frame" or box on your page (not the sidebar nav)

Your navbar `overflow` property is set to `hidden` - which prevents the scrolling that you are looking for. It also has no parent element aside from the doc body, so unless you want the scrolling on the navbar itself, you'll need to add a parent with `overflow: auto;`.

**Example:**

```css
html, body{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
}
.content{ 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: pink;
}    
.header {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 260px;
        min-height: 100%;
        padding: 0 0 0 50px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
    .header .logo {
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left: -50px;
    }
    .header nav ul {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 35px;
        margin-left: -15px;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .header nav ul li {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    .header nav ul li a {
        color: #000000;
        font-family:"raleway-regular", arial;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    .header nav ul li a:hover {
        color: #8AE6B8;
    }
    .header nav ul li a:active {
        color: #CC99FF;
    }
    .transition {
        width:50%;
        height: 30px;
        position: relative;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .transition:hover {
        width:100%;
        height: 30px;
        position: relative;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .sideBar {
        width:75%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        padding:0px;
        margin-left:20%;
    }
    .header .footer {
        margin-top: 30%;
    }
    .header ul.social {
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
        /* For Webkit browsers */
        filter: gray;
        /* For IE 6 - 9 */
        -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
        /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
    }
    .header ul.social li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 15px 15px 4px;
    }
    .header ul.social li a {
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    .header .rights p {
        color: #000000;
        font-family:"raleway-regular", arial;
        font-size: 11px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
    .header .rights a {
        font-family:"raleway-bold", arial;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo"> <a href="index.html">
    <img src="img/logo.png"/>
   </a>

    </div>
    <!-- end logo -->
    <div id="menu_icon"></div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="about.html" class="selected">About</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="resume.html" class="selected">Resume</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="skills.html" class="selected">Skills</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="gallery.html" class="selected">Map&nbsp;Gallery</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="thesis.html" class="selected">Thesis</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="transition">
                <div class="sideBar">
                    <li><a href="contact.html" class="selected">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--end sidebar-->
    <div class="footer clearfix">
        <ul class="social clearfix">
            <li><a href="mailto:md@outlook.com" class="email" target="_blank" data-title="Email"><img src="img/email.png"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/MD/b6/90b/26b?trk=pub-pbmap" class="linkedin" target="_blank" data-title="LinkedIn"><img src="img/linkedin.png"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/mD" class="twitter" target="_blank" data-title="Twitter"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MD" class="facebook" target="_blank" data-title="Facebook"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end social -->
        <div class="rights">
            <p>Copyright © MD</p>
        </div>
        <!-- end rights -->
    </div>
    <!-- end footer -->
</div>            
<!-- end header -->
            </div>
```